# SpringBoot issues with SessionScope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I run a SpringBoot application with MyBatis.

And i have a MyBatis's mapper like this:

```java
    @Component
    @Mapper
    public interface AccountMapper {
        @Insert("insert into dc_account(identification,nickname,username,password) values (#{identification},#{nickname},#{username},#{password})")
        public int insert(Account account);
        @Update("update dc_account set identification=#{identification},nickname=#{nickname},username=#{username},password=#{password}")
        public int update(Account account);

        @Select("select * from dc_account where username=#{username} and password=#{password}")
        @Results(
            id = "account",
            value = {
                @Result(property = "identification", column = "identification"),
                @Result(property = "nickname", column = "nickname"),
                @Result(property = "username", column = "username"),
                @Result(property = "password", column = "password")   
            }
        )
        Account select(Account account);
    }
```

Account class is:

```java
@Component
@SessionScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Account{
    @Value("1")
    int identification;
    @Value("1")
    String nickname;
    @Value("1")
    String username;
    @Value("1")
    String password;
//getter and setter
}
```

Controller:

```java
@Autowired
AccountMapper accountMapper;
@Autowired
Account account;
//.......
@RequestMapping("/login")
    Account login(
        @RequestParam("username")String username,
        @RequestParam("password")String password){
            account.setUsername(username);
            account.setPassword(password);
            accountMapper.select(account);
            return account;
    }
```

And when i enter url `localhost:8080/login?username=1&password=1`

It report [image]

and if i remove the `@SessionScope` annotation of `class Account` everything works fine.

I don't know where went wrong...can anybody give some advice?

Comment: which version of jackson ?

Comment: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: what puzzled me is when i remove the @SessionScope ,everything work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

After a whole afternoon's searching.

Here is what i think:

When I change the controller into this code below,everything still works fine.

So there is nothing wrong with mybatis

```java
@RequestMapping("/login")
    Account login(
        @RequestParam("username")String username,
        @RequestParam("password")String password){
            account.setUsername(username);
            account.setPassword(password);
            return accountMapper.select(account);
            //return account;
    }
```

**But** it i change the code slightly into

```java
@RequestMapping("/login")
    Account login(
        @RequestParam("username")String username,
        @RequestParam("password")String password){
            account.setUsername(username);
            account.setPassword(password);
            //return accountMapper.select(account);
            return account;
    }
```

It then report the same error message that i mention in the question.

I think the `@SessionScope`'s bean(which is Account class) is already managed by SpringBoot's ioc container,

and if i return the same session scope bean from that controller method,

these two bean point to the same thing,that causing some kind of self-reference.